# How can I configure Launcher activity programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-applicationinfo

I am working on an app with two activities : `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity`. When the user first opens the app he will login and his credentials (username and token) are saved in `Preferences`.

Now, if the user opens the app again then `MainActivity` should start. I tried to switch between these activities in Application class and removed intent-filter for LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY from manifest, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way of switching between Launcher Activities programmatically on basis of saved preferences?

Comment: check if logged in at LoginActivity using Preferences, then open MainAcivity and finish LoginActivity if user is logged in

Comment: If I check preferences in MainActivity then it will be better, as switching to login activity will occur less no of times, right ?

Comment: could be, it depends on your business, if some data is fetched once mainAcitivty is loaded, then you might get some errors if user is not logged in, otherwise it could be fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Long story short, you cannot change the `Activity` that is launched by default. Update: There is an alternative as described by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29517717/503508) in another answer.

However, there are reasonable work arounds. In your `MainActivity` you can check whether the user is logged in and immediately redirect them to the `LoginActivity`. That has the added benefit of automatically returning to the `MainActivity` after you have logged in.

Alternatively, you can always go first to the `LoginActivity`, and if the user is already logged in, send them to the `MainActivity` (rewrite the Intent history to remove the return to `LoginActivity` or set the [noHistory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory) flag in the manifest).

Answer (score 28):

> Is there any way of switching between Launcher Activities programmatically on basis of saved preferences ?

You can try this:

Step #1: Have `LoginActivity` have the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` as normal, and have `MainActivity` have no `<intent-filter>`.

Step #2: Have [an `<activity-alias>` element in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html) pointing to `MainActivity` that has the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`.

Step #3: Put `android:enabled="false"` on the `<activity-alias>`, so it is disabled by default, so when the app is first installed, the only launcher icon is for `LoginActivity`.

Step #4: When the user logs in, and you want to change so `MainActivity` is the launcher activity, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to make the `<activity-alias>` enabled and to disable the `LoginActivity`.

Not all home screens will detect this change on the fly, and for those, the device would need to reboot in all likelihood to pick up the change. For this reason, it would be better to stick with a single launcher activity. If you want, that launcher activity could have `Theme.NoDisplay` and simply route to the correct "real" activity in `onCreate()`, per Fahim's answer.

Answer (score 4):

An activity doesn't necessarily require a UI, so you can use the launcher activity in the manifest to lauch any activity you desire.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to make MainActivity launcher activity, as usual.
Then check in `MainActivity#onCreate(Bundle)` via `SharedPreferences` if the user already logged in and, if not, start `LoginActivity` immediately. When user logs in, save the boolean flag indicating that user logged in in `SharedPreferences` and finish `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know changing launcher programmatically is not possible, but it also doesn't make sense.

On your LoginActivity's `onCreate` check if a username and token is already saved, if it is try to login with that automatically, is succeed redirect to your MainAcivity. Depending on the way your app works you can have a variable that checks if a user is logged in or not, if he is the LoginActivity would redirect him to MainActivity without trying to log in again.

```
//LoginActivity
onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    /* ... */

    //Or whatever you use to login (it could also go inside a thread or an AsyncTask
    if (login())
    {
        //Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        //Start Activity
        startActivity(intent);

        //Finish this activity, so when user pressed back the login activity will not come forth and  the app will exit 
        //this looks like when a user has logged in once, the login screen will not be visible to him (unless you want to)
        finish();
    }
}
```

You can also configure it to save username and token only if a login is successful which means the above code can be modified like this:

```
if (getUsername() != null)
{
    /* Start Main Activity */
}
```

This won't attempt to log in, but it knows the credential are right since it has logged in at least once with them.

If your app behaves a different way that these methods do not work, feel free to say so, I may be able to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

You can jsut add Intent after OnCreate to the XML you want to show in the beginning  of your APP.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //add some code to detect if user is logged in
       if (user != null){
           Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, YourDesiredActivity.class);
           startActivity(in);
       } 
   ..........
   ...........
```