# How to continue on the last activity when the app is closed and started again?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

So, for my Android course this semester we're making an app of our own choosing, and due to a lack of ideas I decided to go with a text-adventure styled game. Nothing too complicated, I know. I'm making sure to be creative and incorporate a lot of different functions of the phone, such as the accelerometer and the camera. But I digress.

I've started planning out how the app should work, and how I should go about coding it, but I've come upon an obstacle fairly early that I need to find a solution for. I'm planning on creating it so that the player is sent from activity to activity, which I think is the best way to go about it, unless I do an endlessly scrolling activity that fills out as the player progresses. And thus, I need a way to make it so that when the player closes the app completely it will "continue" on the last activity before shutdown, so the progress is saved in a way.

I'm not sure if this is possible to do, and if so, are there any other ways I can achieve the same sort of result?

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` to save the user state and retrieve it when needed. It is your job to implement the logic to go to the correct screen/activity based on this state.

Comment: When you say "save the user state" do you then mean it saves the screen/activity the user is standing at when the action occurs?

Comment: It's up to you how to model your user state. For example, for a book reader app, you could save the last page the user was reading when he left the app and resume at the same page when he comes back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can change your starting activity programmatically. You can save the activity that you want to start with in a file and redirect to this activity from your main activity every time your application starts (on the onCreate() method of your main activity).

As it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517277/how-can-i-configure-launcher-activity-programmatically-in-android).

Comment: Okay, so basically, it's impossible to do what I was thinking of, because the activity I would like to start with would change every time the player started up the app.

Comment: You could update the file with the current activity every time the user progresses in your game.

Answer (score 0):

As someone has suggested, save the current state (ie: what `Activity` is currently shown) in `SharedPreferences`. When the user launches your app, the root `Activity` (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) will be started. In `onCreate()` of the root `Activity`, read the saved state from the `SharedPreferences` and launch that `Activity` immediately.