# Pragmatically set Intent Categories - Home Button Action

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an app that has intent filters set to `CategoryHome` and `CategoryDefault`

```
[IntentFilter
  (
    new[] 
    { 
      Intent.ActionMain 
    }, 
    Categories = new[] 
    {
      Intent.CategoryHome, 
      Intent.CategoryDefault 
    }
  )
]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
...
```

Is it possible to change this on the fly?

Comment: What's you mean "on the fly"? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I'd like to be able to change this setting within the app while it is running..

Answer (score 0):

> Pragmatically set Intent Categories - Home Button Action

You can't do this directly, but you could disable/enable particular `Activities` of your app.
 So you could have your Home app as disabled by default, then if a user wanted to use it, they could enable it programmatically.

You could refer to [CommonsWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142101/how-to-create-disable-intent-filter-by-programmable-way/14142215#14142215) :

> You can neither enable, disable, or create `<intent-filter>`s programmatically.
>
> However, in your case, you only have one `<intent-filter>` per component. In that case, you can enable and disable the *component* programmatically, via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. In your case, enabling or disabling the activity would have the same basic effect as enabling or disabling its `<intent-filter>`.

Other useful link :

- [Android: Can I enable/disable an activity's intent filter programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408086/android-can-i-enable-disable-an-activitys-intent-filter-programmatically/10403074#10403074)
- [How can I configure Launcher activity programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517277/how-can-i-configure-launcher-activity-programmatically-in-android)