# If Login 1 time, open MainActivity when ever app launch again?

Tags: java, android

My App flow is:

Start app with *SplashActivity -> LoginActivity -> MainActivity*

I use session manager class to check remember button and now its flow is:

*SplashActivity ->  MainActivity*

But I need to Login if check is true, then Next time when I open my app it will directly start from the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can not change the defined in intent-filter on run time.. but there is a way to achieve what you need using `<activity-alias>`

As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29517717/886001), you need to follow these steps:

1. Make your `SplashActivity` have the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` and declare your `MainActivity` with no `<intent-filter>`.
2. make [an `<activity-alias>` element in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html) pointing to `MainActivity` that has the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`.
3. Put `android:enabled="false"` on the `<activity-alias>`, so it is disabled by default, so when the app is first installed or the user is not logged in, the `SplashActivity`.
4. When the user logs in, and you want to change so `MainActivity` is the launcher activity, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to make the `<activity-alias>` enabled and to disable the `SplashActivity`.

   ```
   // after login/logout success enable/disable components as required
   // use the correct "packagename", "alias" and activities names
   getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                               new ComponentName("packagename", "alias"),
                               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 
                               PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
   try {
       getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                               new ComponentName("packagename", "SplashActivity"),
                               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                               PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   define your alias like this

   ```
   <activity-alias
       android:name=".Blahblah"
       android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/splashactivity_name"
       android:icon="@drawable/icon_splashactivity">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity-alias>
   ```

   with this when you enable your alias it'll work as your launcher and it'll make the application start with `MainActivity`

When the user logs out you can do the same thing to change back the default configuration

Comment: "Application not found" is giving when click on app

Comment: How did you define your activity-alias? did use provide the right target activity and intent-filter?

Comment: In Manifest
<activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:targetActivity=".activity.MainActivity1"
            android:enabled="false"></activity-alias>

Comment: The intent-filter launcher should be set for the alias and not the splash activity.. you need to uninstall/reinstall app to reset the change for test

Comment: Sorry to Disturb you again @A.A but i tell you from initial steps 
My Scenario is app Start from (step 1) Splash Activity than Login Activity is Open,(step 2) On Login Activity I have remember me checkbox.
If user checked = true than press loginBtn than Session save this value and when again app Start than it should open MainActivity
other wise app open as it from step(1).

Comment: I know.. but you need to have your activity-alias have a launcher intent filter too so when you enable you can start with MainActivity without getting "application not found".. also choose another name for your activity-alias

Comment: Thanks #A.A but i found an other way to do this 
I'm using handler class On Splash in final block i set to move in login and further in Main Class
Now i set checked on splashClass which check session have data or not if preset than redirect to Main Class other wise process continue as it and from logout buton in mainClass i clear session data

Answer (score 0):

I found an other way to do this I'm using handler class On Splash in final block i call LoginClass and further move in MainClass
 Now I changed some code. First It checked on SplashClass that SessionClass have data or not. If data present than redirect to MainClass and from Logout button in MainClass I clear session. 
If data not present, process start from beginning .